# Elastic Search Street Range Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search

We have two fields Street Number 1 & Street Number 2 in Elastic Search. We also have an Address field in Elastic Search and Address is a combination of 2 fields with some other fields. So we have an address as:

- 1604-1612 Calver Building
- 1608- 1645 Park House

If the user is searching with 1610 both the address should be returned.

Any help on how the query can be formed?

Comment: I would experiment with the [`range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) data type and maybe create another field of that type that contains the min and max street number for a given address.

Comment: We are looking to store both Street Number 1 & Street Number 2 in elastic search. So my logic should be > than Street Number 1 & < than Street Number 2. But I am not sure if range query supports that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to leverage the [`range`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) data type and store the min and max street number in that field.

In your mapping, you'd have something like this:

```
PUT property_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "street_number_range": {
          "type": "integer_range"
        },
        "street_name": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can add your two documents like this:

```
PUT property_index/_doc/1
{
  "street_number_range" : { 
    "gte" : 1604,
    "lte" : 1612
  },
  "street_name": "Calver Building"
}

PUT property_index/_doc/2
{
  "street_number_range" : { 
    "gte" : 1608,
    "lte" : 1645
  },
  "street_name": "Park House"
}
```

Finally, your query would look like this and wold return both documents

```
GET property_index/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "street_number_range" : {
        "value": 1610
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*UPDATE*

You can also search for a range with the following query:

```
GET property_index/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "range" : {
      "street_number_range" : {
        "gte": 1600,
        "lte": 1650
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this.

Comment: Also how would the reverse work? If the user is searching with a range like 1600-1650 then we should get back both the addresses.

Comment: Thanks Val for your answer. I am kind of stuck on how I can use them in a cross fields query. Can we have a range inside cross fields