# Elastic Search Query Where value exists between 2 field values

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to figure out how to construct a query against elastic search where the query value exists between the range of 2 field values.

Lets say I have a template

```
{
     "template": "addresses",
     "mappings": { 
         "addresses": {
             "properties": {
                   "street_number_1": { "type": "integer" },
                   "street_number_2": { "type": "integer" },
                    ... //other unimportant fields
              }
          }
 }
```

Based on the above definition,  If I have an address of  100-120 High Street,  where street_number_1 is 100 and street_number_2 is 120,  if I were to perform a Search for 112 High Street, this record should be returned as it is between 100 and 120.   What kind of elastic search function/query would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. With your current mapping, you can use two [range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "street_number_1": {
              "lte": 112
            }
          }
        },
         {
          "range": {
            "street_number_2": {
              "gte": 112
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The second option involves changing your mapping to use an [integer range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) for the street number. Define your street number mapping like this:

```
PUT addresses
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "street_number": {
          "type": "integer_range"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index your address document like this:

```
PUT addresses/_doc/1
{
  "street_number" : { 
    "gte" : 100,
    "lte" : 120
  }
}
```

And finally query it like this:

```
POST addresses/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "street_number" : {
        "value": 112
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think one would perform better than the other?

Comment: And I forgot I answer the same question here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716910/elastic-search-street-range-search/48717296#48717296

Comment: Regarding performance, you have the full story [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/numeric-and-date-ranges-in-elasticsearch-just-another-brick-in-the-wall) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-planning-for-range-queries-in-elasticsearch)